# Efficient way to write request/response mocks for e2e tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

Currently at my place we are using protractor to write Angular e2e tests. One of the most time consuming and tedious steps is to write out all the network request/response to be EXACTLY like what you would expect. So when a page makes 5 api calls to our backend, I usually have to inspect from Chrome's network tab and copy the data one by one. I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's not a matter of testing, but the way how API is implemented.

If I understood you well you're sending 5 requests to the same endpoint (correct me if I'm wrong).
Maybe it's possible to pass an array with data to that endpoint. If it's like that, maybe it's more efficient to send one request instead of five?

If not - the only way you could do is loop over requests.